# Run a cron job from within a php file

Tags: php

I have a problem where my hosting company won't let me run a cron job in this format from my control panel:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/sites/MYDOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron
```

Or:

```
www.MYDOMAINNAME.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron
```

Now if i run the second job in a browser i.e.:

```
www.MYDOMAINNAME.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron
```

this works fine in a browser

My support says I have to create a file to run the URL. The only problem is I don’t know how to run a URL in PHP. I have asked a few sites. But nothing. My file is called `bump.php` and has the following code:

```
lynx -dump http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron
```

this is what i have in the file

```
<?php


echo file_get_contents('DOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron');

?>
```

Comment: you can NOT use urls like that on a command line. `?` will be seen as a wildcard, and the entire query string is NOT seen as a query string. it'll be seen as part of the file path. In cron, you're dealing with the filesystem. there's no webserver, there's no url parser. there's just shells and files+paths.

Comment: That last file is no PHP code.

Comment: What are you allowed to run ?

Comment: echo file_get_contents('http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron'); should call your URL.

Comment: echo file_get_contents('MYDOMAIN.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron'); is that the full line of code?

Comment: @MikeAsp Put this in a php file and call the file using cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to access the file in question via your webserver, not directly by file access. If you access it by file-access, it will just return the php code and not execute it.

There are several options on how to access files via webserver. One is your shown method with `file_get_contents`. You will need to add `http://` in front of the url to tell PHP that you want it accessed remotly and not as a local file.

`file_get_contents` is not allways configured to allow remotely downloading files. In these cases, it will not work. You can check this link to see the configuration setting for remote accessing files:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Another solution is to use the **curl** extension (if available)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

There are other extensions if curl is also not available...

Comment: brilliant that worked great even out puts the cron job results. thanks